# Gitlab-CI CE executor /usr/bin/bash: line 113: git: command not found

Tags: bash, docker, gitlab-ci

I have a local gitlab ce server and gitlab-ci runner, all running on docker container. And I just want to test out if the gitlab-ci is working with minimal code in .gitlab-ci.yml; However, it ended up with the ci does not run at all, and git version wasn't posting as well, and showing error codes

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.2.0 (58ba2b95)
  on GitLab-cicd-practice GPdsWyY7
Preparing the "shell" executor 00:00
Using Shell executor...
Preparing environment 00:00
Running on gitlab...
Getting source from Git repository 00:01
Fetching changes...
bash: line 113: git: command not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Code for .gitlab-ci.yml

```
build:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - git --version
  script: echo hello
  

test:
  script: echo
  stage: test
  needs: [build]
```

Comment: For _any_ "command not found" error, the first question is "is the tool installed?", followed by "_where_ is the tool installed?" and "which locations are in the PATH at the time of execution?". If this is in a Docker container, you need to worry about whether git is installed _in the container_, not whether it's installed on your host.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this, the runner is running using shell, therefore the problem is that git is not installed on the machine that's running the gitlab-runner.

To fix this just install git on the machine so that the gitlab-runner can use it.

If you're on linux you should be able to install it with apt or yum

```
apt install git
```

or

```
yum install git
```